# com capturar o width da tela de impressão com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Galera tenho o seguinte código:

HTML

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <th>
            teste
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY

```
    // Imprime a página
    window.print();
    // Redireciona página
    window.location = 'link';
```

Bom o problema que eu tenho e o seguinte. Quando imprimi em uma folha A4 a tabela ocupa toda a tela de forma correta. Porém montei um recibo e quero imprimir ele em uma impressora não fiscal, e usa fita termina de 80mm, e a tabela fica cortada, como se imprimisse apenas metade.

Bom a solução que tenho em monte, e fazer o jQuery capturar o width da folha de impressão e mudar o css da tabela.

Alguém sabe fazer isso? Ou tem alguma solução melhor?

Comment: Tentou usar medidas em milimetros? Se bem que usar tecnologia "web" para isso sempre vai ser improviso, mas talvez usar medidas absolutas quebre um galho. O que é importante entender na atual dificuldade é: sempre que usar martelo com parafuso, o resultado vai ficar a desejar.

Comment: tentei colocar tudo dentro de uma `div` com `width: 350px;` porém esta saindo tudo minúsculo. Deve ter alguma forma de gerar um recibinho via web para ser impresso em uma impressora não fiscal

Comment: Use mm e não px. Ponha as fontes em mm e a largura em mm (e mesmo assim, nem sempre funciona).

Answer (score 1):

Ainda não é possível saber informações da tela de impressão no JS, por isso mesmo você não pode capturar a largura da tela de impressão no jQuery.

Algo que você pode fazer é usar @media queries do CSS3 e fazer mudanças na página de acordo com a largura/altura da tela de impressão.

Isso pode ser suficiente.

(Em `min-width` você deve especificar as larguras das folhas.)

```
/* semelhante à 90mm */
@media print and (min-width: 80mm) {
    table {
        width: 350px;
    }
}

/* ... */
@media print and (min-width: 121mm) {
    table {
        width: 450px;
    }
}

/* +A5, A4, ... */
@media print and (min-width: 152mm) {
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Você pode declarar quantos `@media print` quiser.

Comment: Tentei aqui mas não deu certo, Olha se estou fazendo certo: `@media print and (min-width: '80mm') {
    .w100 {
        width: 350px;
    }
}`

Comment: @HugoBorges Tire as aspas

Comment: Talvez isso ajude na questão do `mm` pois não acho certo usar esta medida e sim o `px` em relação a Web: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.pt_BR.html

Comment: @nicematt poderia me dar uma exemplo de como eu colocar 350px para quando a folhar for menor ou igual a 90mm e se for folha A4 ficar 100%

Comment: @iLeonardoCarvalho eu recomendaria você ler seus próprios links para poder opinar. De acordo com seu próprio link, mm não é bom PARA TELA, e o usuário quer a medida no papel. Medida absoluta é justamente o problema que ele descreveu na pergunta: _"Elas não são recomendadas para uso em tela porque tamanhos de tela variam muito. Uma tela grande pode ter 60cm (24in); uma pequena e portátil, talvez apenas 8cm."_ Ainda: _"Não, as unidades não têm nada a ver com as propriedades, mas têm tudo a ver com a mídia de saída: tela ou papel. "_

Comment: Bem queria mais só uma conversão mesmo não usar o `mm` e sim o `px` pois semanticamente cada unidade inserida dentro de uma página pode dificultar na manutenção e padronizar seja a melhor alternativa e usando os comentários para lembrar do valor inserido.

Comment: Aliás, só pra complementar, tirado do link recomendado: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CPYEd.png

Comment: bom pelo o que eu pude notar a linha `@media print and (min-width: 152mm) {` e capaz de reconhecer o width da tela ok. não tem como eu colocar o valor do width da tela em PX na propriedade width?

Comment: @HugoBorges Não, o CSS não oferece fazer isso, ou pelo menos atualmente.